# Delete Duplicate records from table having single column

Tags: mysql

I Have table which has record as below

Table Name : t1

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
1
3
4
```

Delete duplicate records without altering or adding any extra column to table.

Desired Output:

```
1 
2 
3 
4
```

Comment: Is there a primary key in your table ? How does someone decides which row to keep amongst the duplicates ?

Comment: Without a PRIMARY KEY, you *don't* really have a table

Comment: No, Only single column. You cannot add any column for same

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with `DELETE JOIN`

```
DELETE t1 FROM contacts t1
        INNER JOIN
    contacts t2 
WHERE
    t1.id < t2.id AND t1.email = t2.email;
```

Comment: Does not satisfy scenario